# Error message from Julia in Atom :"UndefVarError: isdebugging not defined'

Tags: julia

I just started learning Julia and installed Atom and Juno. However, I could not write any Julia code in the Atom console, and kept receiving the error message "PowerShell version < 3 encountered. Running without wrapper (interrupts won't work)" and "UndefVarError: isdebugging not defined".

I have already changed the path of julia bin file, but got this error message and I am not sure what to do.

Comment: What version of Julia? Sounds like you have an old version, or a beta version.

Comment: @ChrisRackauckas my Julia version is 0.60 prealpha

Comment: Juno probably isn't compatible with that version yet. As it says, it's pre-alpha. Only use Julia's nightly versions if you have a very specific reason to. Give v0.5 a try for now.

Comment: Quoting from the website: "The nightly builds are for developer previews and not intended for normal use. You can expect many packages not to work with this version." One of those packages which has not upgraded yet is the debugger Gallium.jl, and it will take a whole lot of work to do so. It will probably be done by the time v0.6 is released, but before v0.6 is released, its the wild west.

Comment: @ChrisRackauckas Thanks so much. I tried the 5.1version and it seemed work well.